# Not contains in child list in RavenDb

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have entity.

```
class Something{
   public List<string> Tags {get;set;}
}
```

Now I need query all entities that does not have given tag.

```
var res = s.Query<Something>()            
           .Where(x => !x.Tags.Any(t => t == "Test3"));
```

Fails with:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to
>   cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpressionN'
>   to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'.

Plain query also does not work:

```
var res = s.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Something>()
           .Where("-Tags:Test3");
```

... it simply returns nothing.

How to write such query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an In extension method that you can use, which will also work with a !

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple:

```
var res = s.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Something>()
  .Where("Tags:(* -Test3)");
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without lucene?